# Can a liquid insulator be electrically charged by touching a charged conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage

> Can a liquid insulator be electrically charged by touching a charged
>   conductor?

I understand that solid insulator will only be charge on the surface where it is touch, but the case is different from liquid which it circulates, so I imagine that slowly liquid insulator will be fully charge due to circulation.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to charge insulators. I have personally charged ping pong balls and rubber balloons, and a certain Robert A. Millikan earned himself a Nobel prize by charging oil droplets.

But to get to the point of your question, you are correct that a liquid object (like Millikan's oil drops) will disperse the charge over its surface because it can flow. Even if the liquid surface is a perfect insulator the charge will eventually disperse over the surface.

Answer (score 0):

Whether charge is transferred between an insulator and a conductor depends on the field strength. If it is high enough charge will move over due to corona discharge. That even works when the two objects are not touching because ions can move through the air.
So yes, if the field strength is sufficient you can charge a liquid insulator but because it is liquid, the charge will immediately flow to the surface and so you won't manage to charge the entire volume.

Comment: Why the charge flow to the surface? Because air is more neutral? Thanks.

Comment: Equal charges repel each other. So the charged particles inside the liquid push each other to the surface.

Comment: So at the bottom will be more neutral than on the surface?

Comment: Not necessarily. Electricity doesn't care about gravity. The charge is pushed outside but in all directions.

Answer (score 0):

So to be loosely technical with this, gravity has no effect on the electrical charge because it is pushed in all directions 360° out. Therefore, the center of your volume of liquid is where it will be most neutral. Example: a jar that is 6 in tall with a diameter of 4 in, to keep numbers simple, the most neutral point of the charged insulating liquid would be at the center of the jar approximately 3 in off the bottom and 2 in off the side.
-Richie The Wrench.©®™ "Keepin' It Lit Since 1979!"©®™

Comment: Please try to keep your answers professional.