# Does all electrical insulator can be electrostatically charged?

Tags: electricity, electrostatics, charge, dielectric, insulators

Does all electrical insulator can be electrostatically charged, or insulator with only dielectric property can? Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Can a liquid insulator be electrically charged by touching a charged conductor?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95634/can-a-liquid-insulator-be-electrically-charged-by-touching-a-charged-conductor)

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by *insulator with only dielectric property*. All insulators (except the vacuum) have a relative permittivity different from 1. Actually even if $\epsilon_r \ne 1$ I think the insulator could still be charged.

Comment: So the amount of charge in the material depend on relative permittivity?

Comment: Does the higher ϵr means that more charges can be stored? Sorry for my ignorance.